# TextField textProperty Listener across embedded scenes JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, listener

This may be a little convoluted but please bear with me.

I have 3 scenes built using SceneBuilder. The first ("Main") I am using as the parent scene. This scene contains 1 `AnchorPane` which holds a `TabPane` and a `ToolBar` which holds 3 `Buttons` ("Previous", "Next" and "Close").

The second scene ("PersonaDetails") contains an `AnchorPane`, a `GridPane` a number of `Textflow` (which I am using as field labels) several `TextField` and `DatePicker`. This whole scene is embedded into one of the tabs on the `TabPane` on the first scene ("Main").

The third scene ("Address") is very similar to the second where it contains an `AnchorPane`, a `GridPane` a number of `Textflow` (which I am using as field labels) several `TextField` and `ComboBox`. This whole scene is embedded into the other tab on the `TabPane` on the first scene ("Main").

(I have included the FXML script for each below)

The application will later include additional scenes on additional tab on the TabPane on the first scene ("Main"). This application will form part of  larger application and is meant to be a kind of wizard that allows new clients to be registered.

Furthermore, each FXML file and its Controller are in separate packages.

This issue I am having is that I need to add `.textProperty()` listeners on several of the `Textfield` so that I can enable, or disable the "Next" `Button` on the first, or parent, scene ("Main").

I have tried the following code in the `MainController` class, but it does not work, although it does not generate any errors.

```
package com.yas.registrationwizard.main;

import com.yas.registrationwizard.personaldetails.PersonalDetailsController;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML AnchorPane apMain;
    @FXML ToolBar tbMain;
    @FXML TabPane tpMain;

    @FXML Button btnPrevious;
    @FXML Button btnNext;
    @FXML Button btnClose;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../personaldetails/PersonalDetails.fxml"));
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PersonalDetailsController personalDetailsController = fxmlLoader.getController();
        personalDetailsController.tfFirstName.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            if(newVal.equals("")) {
                btnNext.setDisable(true);
            } else {
                btnNext.setDisable(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The FXML scripts are as follows:

**Main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane fx:id="apMain" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.yas.registrationwizard.main.MainController">
    <children>
        <ToolBar fx:id="tbMain" layoutX="259.0" layoutY="339.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="355.0">
            <items>
                <Pane prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="370.0" />
                <Button fx:id="btnPrevious" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="65.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="65.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="Previous" />
                <Button fx:id="btnNext" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="13.0" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="65.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="65.0" mnemonicParsing="false"  prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="Next" />
                <Button fx:id="btnClose" layoutX="66.0" layoutY="13.0" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="65.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="65.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="Close" />
            </items>
        </ToolBar>
        <TabPane fx:id="tpMain" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="335.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0">
            <tabs>
                <Tab fx:id="tabPersonalDetails" text="Personal Deatils">
               <content>
                  <fx:include fx:id="apPersonalDetails" source="../personaldetails/PersonalDetails.fxml" />
               </content></Tab>
                <Tab fx:id="tabAddress" text="Address">
               <content>
                  <fx:include fx:id="apAddress" source="../address/Address.fxml" />
               </content></Tab>
            </tabs>
        </TabPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Address**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane fx:id="apAddress" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="325.0" prefWidth="590.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.yas.registrationwizard.address.AddressController">
   <children>
      <GridPane fx:id="gpAddress" layoutX="195.0" layoutY="103.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="103.0" minWidth="3.0" prefWidth="82.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="219.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="155.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="422.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="274.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="93.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="78.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="295.0" text="House Name / Number:" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin></Label>
            <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="246.0" text="Address Line 1:" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin></Label>
            <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="239.0" text="Address Line 2:" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin></Label>
            <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="234.0" text="Town / City:" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin></Label>
            <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="237.0" text="Region / County:" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin></Label>
            <TextField fx:id="tfHseNameNum" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfAddLine1" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfAddLine2" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfTownCity" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfRegionCounty" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="234.0" text="Postcode:" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="tfPostcode" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="234.0" text="Country:" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="8">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <ComboBox fx:id="cboCountry" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="294.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**PersonDetails**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="apPersonalDetails" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="325.0" prefWidth="590.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.yas.registrationwizard.personaldetails.PersonalDetailsController">
   <children>
      <GridPane fx:id="gpPersonalDetails" layoutX="195.0" layoutY="103.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="80.0" minWidth="37.0" prefWidth="37.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="236.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="236.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="422.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="277.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="80.0" minWidth="38.0" prefWidth="41.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="tfFirstName" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfMidNameInit" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfLastName" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <DatePicker fx:id="dpDoB" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="365.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfNatInsNum" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
            <TextFlow fx:id="tflFirstName" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="162.0" style="-fx-text-alignment: right;" styleClass="txtFlow" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin></TextFlow>
            <TextFlow fx:id="tflLastName" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="162.0" style="-fx-text-alignment: right;" styleClass="txtFlow" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
               <padding>
                  <Insets right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </TextFlow>
            <TextFlow fx:id="tflDoB" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="162.0" style="-fx-text-alignment: right;" styleClass="txtFlow" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
               <padding>
                  <Insets right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </TextFlow>
            <TextFlow fx:id="tflNatInsNum" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="162.0" style="-fx-text-alignment: right;" styleClass="txtFlow" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6">
               <padding>
                  <Insets right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </TextFlow>
            <TextFlow fx:id="tflMidNameInit" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="162.0" style="-fx-text-alignment: right;" styleClass="txtFlow" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <padding>
                  <Insets right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </TextFlow>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The folder structure for the project is shown in the image below:

[image: Folder Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I am bit confused with the wording "scene" in the question. I believe what you mentioned in the question is about handling the nodes, because all the fxmls are handled in the same Scene/Stage.

Anyway, the main problem of the issue lies in the MainController initialize method. You are loading a new instance of PersonalDetailsController and working on it, instead of working on the controller that is actually binded to MainController.

<strike>When including fxmls in an fxml, the sub fxml's controller will be already injected to the main fxml controller.</strike> So I believe changing your MainController code as below should work as expected.

**Update:** Sorry for a bit misleading info. The correct thing is, you need to inject the controller with a certain naming convention. If you are including an fxml using fx:include, to get the controller you need to inject with a naming convention `<fxid>Controller` and `<fxid>` for getting the node reference.

So considering your example, for the given fx:include line:

```
<fx:include fx:id="apPersonalDetails" source="../personaldetails/PersonalDetails.fxml" />
```

your code in MainController should be:

```
// For controller reference
@FXML PersonalDetailsController apPersonalDetailsController;

// For Node reference
@FXML AnchorPane apPersonalDetails;
```

So the updated code will be as below:

```
import com.yas.registrationwizard.personaldetails.PersonalDetailsController;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML AnchorPane apMain;
    @FXML ToolBar tbMain;
    @FXML TabPane tpMain;

    @FXML Button btnPrevious;
    @FXML Button btnNext;
    @FXML Button btnClose;

    @FXML PersonalDetailsController apPersonalDetailsController;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        apPersonalDetailsController.tfFirstName.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            if(newVal.equals("")) {
                btnNext.setDisable(true);
            } else {
                btnNext.setDisable(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the wording. I am still a newbie at this. I tried the code you gave, but I am still getting a nullPointerException at the line "personalDetailsController.tfFirstName.textProperty().addListener..."

Comment: Sorry for a bit misleaded info. Updated my answer.